# Errors Changing /boot/config.txt externally

Tags: pi-4, config.txt, sudo, raspberry-pi-os-bullseye

I was overclocking my pi, and I went a little overkill,  so now it wont boot.

Im trying to change config.txt back to its previous state externally, but I don't have the permissions to do it.  I tried changing the permissions externally, but I don't have the permissions to do that either.  I dunno what to do now.  Im running raspbian bullseye.

(EDIT: RESOLVED! I was looking on the ext4 partition with home on it.  i was looking in the boot folder there.  My mistake)

Comment: config.txt is a text file on a FAT partrition. It has NO permissions - you can edit it on ANY system!

Comment: oooo duh what a stooge i am!